# Докер перстал работать

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Включаю комп, захожу в проект, набираю:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

и получаю ошибку:

> **ERROR**: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run
>   docker-machine start default.

Следую совету докера и выполняю команду:

```
docker-machine start default
```

на что в ответ получаю:

> Machine "default" is already running.

Comment: *is already running* — наверно, осталось что-то от неудачного запуска (скорее всего того, что прописан у вас для автозапуска). смотрите логи, разбирайтесь, почему запуск был неудачным.

Comment: mac, linux, windows?